# Batch file to read multiple lines

Tags: file, batch-file

I have created one batch file to check date in first line and EOF flag in last line. If the requirements are met then proceed. Bellow is the batch file.

```
@ECHO OFF 
SET LOGFILE_DATE=%DATE:~4,2%.%DATE:~7,2%.%DATE:~10,4% 
SET LOGFILE_TIME=%TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2% 
SET LOGFILE="C:\N-able\Projects\AML\NDB Bank\devinda\AML_Data_Auto-%LOGFILE_DATE%-%LOGFILE_TIME%.log" 
call :Logit >> %LOGFILE% 
exit /b 0 

:Logit
::
set "firstLine" 
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\N-able\Projects\AML\NDB Bank\devinda\AML_handshake.txt) do ( 
        If not defined firstLine set "firstLine=%%A" 
        set Lastline=%%A) 
)
set "date=%firstLine:~9,8%"

REM *** FIRST CHECK *** 
if "EOF" NEQ "%Lastline%" goto fail 

REM *** SECOND CHECK ***
set day=-1
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "data=%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%" 
if "%data%" NEQ "%date%" goto fail
exit /b

goto prog 
:prog 
...Some Codes...

:fail 
echo Initial Check Failed, Process Terminated
```

And bellow is the text file.

```
AML.DATA|2016-06-16
PORT_DATA|560538
NDB_AML_AA|43063
NDB_AML_LD|12878
NDB_AML_REPO|496
NDB_AML_TRAN|84596
NDB_AML_JOINT_AC|219873
NDB_AML_CUS_REL_PRTY|43
NDB_AML_BICCODE|108292
CUSTOMER_MASTER|684124
CATEGORY.MASTER|3288
DEPT.MASTER|2527
COUNTRY.MASTER|251
CUSTOMER.STATUS.MASTER|26
INDUSTRY.MASTER|65
JOB.TITLE.MASTER|22
COMPANY.MASTER|121
TRANSACTION.MASTER|3133
RELATION.MASTER|56
NDB_AML_TBILL_TBOND|2845
EOF
```

Even though the date and EOF flag has met it always goes to `:fail`.

```
C:\N-able\Projects\AML\NDB Bank\devinda>set "firstLine"  

C:\N-able\Projects\AML\NDB Bank\devinda>for /F "tokens=*" %A in (C:\N-able\Projects\AML\NDB Bank\devinda\AML_handshake.txt) do (
If not defined firstLine set "firstLine=%A"   
 set Lastline=%A 
) 

C:\N-able\Projects\AML\NDB Bank\devinda>set "date=~9,8" 

C:\N-able\Projects\AML\NDB Bank\devinda>REM *** FIRST CHECK ***  

C:\N-able\Projects\AML\NDB Bank\devinda>if "EOF" NEQ "" goto fail  

C:\N-able\Projects\AML\NDB Bank\devinda>echo Initial Check Failed, Process Terminated  
Initial Check Failed, Process Terminated
```

I need some help how to solve it.

Comment: Does your `:prog` section end somehow like `goto :eof` or `exit /b`? If not, the program simply continues to `:fail`.

Comment: @Melebius I don't have :eof and do I need to put exit /b?

Comment: Well, not necessarily because your program seems to never get there since there is an `exit /b` before `:prog`.

Comment: Remove `@echo off` and check the output...

Comment: ... and your logfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set "date=%firstLine:~9,8%"
```

this is too short, it gives you `YYYY-MM-` only, but you compare it to `YYYY-MM-DD`, so the `if` can never get true. Change it to:

```
set "date=%firstLine:~9,10%"
```

... and *please* don't use `%date%` as an variable name - it's a system variable; changing it can lead to unpredictable behaviour in other parts of the code. Choose another variable name.

Comment: Still it's not working. Is it correct they way I have mentioned two For loops?